# Place and scale text onto of responsive image

Tags: html, css

I want to place text (I plan on dynamically generating this text later, hence why it isn't in the image) over an image (where the white rectangle is) and have the text scale along with the responsive image. I have successfully placed text over the image but I am having trouble keeping it aligned with where it is supposed to be in the image (the white rectangle).

I realize that if I was to make the rectangle in the image in the center this would be easier, however that's not an option in this scenario.

How can I keep this text in the white rectangle and keep it scaled with the image?

Edit: Apologies, the red arrows are placeholders for a mockup I am currently designing.

Thanks

```css
p{
        z-index: 100;
        position: absolute;
        color: black;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        left: 150px;
        top: 275px;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="flex flex-wrap w-full justify-center content-center px-12">
    <div class="flex flex-wrap lg:items-center min-h-screen">
        <div class="flex flex-col w-full lg:w-1/2 justify-center">
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sxnQAi2.png" class="object-contain max-h-full">
            <p id="text">Dynamic text!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-wrap w-full lg:w-1/2 justify-center">
            <h3 class="text-3xl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! do you want just place this text in box or want to try with some other method?

Comment: Hi @JaswinderKaur - I don’t understand your question. What other methods?

Comment: I mean instead of placing this text in box we will set box around this text

Comment: Both options are very interesting - could you show me both?

Comment: Sure give me few min.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```html
    <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
    <div class="flex flex-wrap w-full justify-center content-center px-12">
        <div class="flex flex-wrap lg:items-center min-h-screen">
            <div class=" relative flex flex-col w-full lg:w-1/2 justify-center">
                <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1625838144804-300f3907c110?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80" class="object-contain max-h-full">
                <p id="text" class="absolute text-white top-2/4 left-2/4 -translate-x-2/4 -translate-y-2/4">Dynamic text!</p>
            </div>
        <div class="flex flex-wrap w-full lg:w-1/2 justify-center">
            <h3 class="text-3xl">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

if you use tailwind css then in parent give relative position and in dynamic text add class position absolute and give transform as I included.

Comment: Yeah but that's centered, can you give me an example using the image I provided?

Comment: try to copy my code and practice.

Comment: `<div class="relative flex flex-col w-full lg:w-1/2 justify-center">
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/sxnQAi2.png" class="object-contain max-h-full">
                <p id="text" class="absolute top-[28%] left-[20%]">Dynamic text!</p>
            </div>`

Answer (score 2):

```css
p#text {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 20px 8px #ddd;
    padding: 40px;
    margin: 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    max-width: 240px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
 <p id="text">Dynamic text!</p>
```

Comment: Oh got it, but I actually need the red arrows and keep scale with the rest of the image. (I am going to be adding more to it)